# Align multiple span's to bottom of footer

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

Seems like a simple task but I just can't figure it out. I have several spans inside my footer and I want them aligned to the bottom.

I've tried adding `vertical-align:bottom` and `bottom:0` but no luck.

```
<footer>
 <span></span>
 <span></span>
 <span></span>
 <span></span>
</footer>
```

It's **important** that they are `spans`!

Below is the css and [here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dDmuW/19/).

```
footer {
    width:100%;
    height:30px;
    background-color:#555;
}
span {
    border-left:1px solid #DDD;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height:50%;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    width:25%;
}
```

**EDIT**
I wasn't clear enough. I want the span's within the footer to align to the bottom. This is what I have now:
[image]

And this is what I want:
[image]

Comment: bottom of what? bottom of the page? or bottom of the `<footer>` tag?

Comment: @Zafar - I've clarified my question a bit.

Comment: @Niklas:check my answer and tell if that is what you intended

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment "no margin, no padding" the only way I see is wrapping your spans into a div and position that div as your needs.

**HTML**

```
<footer>
    <div>
       <span></span>
       <span></span>
       <span></span>
       <span></span>
    </div>
</footer>
```

**CSS**

```
footer {
    width:100%;
    height:30px;
    background-color:#555;
    position: relative;
}
div{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    height:50%;
    width: 100%;
}
span {
    border-left:1px solid #DDD;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height:100%;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    width:25%;
    background-color:#777;
 }
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5rL9S/)**

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question correctly then here is the Fiddle for that:

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/dDmuW/18/)

```
footer {
width:100%;
height:30px;
background-color:#555;
bottom:0px;
position:absolute;
}
span {

border-left:1px solid #DDD;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
height:50%;
display:block;
float:left;
width:25%;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've updated my question now. I want the spans within the footer to align to the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

this is what you need

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/YRt6x/)

```
footer {
    width:100%;
    height:30px;
    background-color:#555;
    position:absolute;

}
span {
    border-left:1px solid #DDD;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height:20px;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    width:25%;
    background-color:#777;
    position:relative;
    margin-top:10px;

}
```

Comment: Hm, so there's no way of actually aligning them to the bottom? Just this "hack"?

Comment: I'm not sure yet. It looks the way I want it, but I don't know if the margin will mess up other things in my footer. If it doesn't, I'll mark this as the answer. I was just curious if there's a way to solve this with alignment, and not margins.